# Derby Apache random NullPointerException

Tags: java, sql, derby

We are having a problem using an embedded Apache Derby. An null pointer exception occurs for no apparent reason. The code uses the EmbeddedSimpleDataSource class to access the DB and the Statement to execute the queries.

**The application runs on java Foundation profil/CDC 1.1 (using cvm instead of a jvm) with the embedded version of Derby**

What is bizarre is that problem is totally random (at least to us, we haven't been able to reproduce it). As u can see from the log below, the exception happens on a very simple select query.

Sometimes we get the exception 3 or times, then everything goes back to normal. (Very rarely all subsequent calls to the DB fail and the only way to regain access is to reboot the application (sometimes we even have to delete the database folder and recreate it))

Here's an extract of the derby log file:

```
   Tue Oct 01 22:51:51 CEST 2013:
Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.10.1.1 - (1458268): instance c013800d-0141-75ca-8140-000000068414 
on database directory /mnt/nand/lu/smarthubdb with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader[ucp=sun.misc.URLClassPath[path=file:/mnt/nand/lu/SmartHub.jar],parent=sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader[ucp=sun.misc.URLClassPath[path=file:/usr/lib/ext/API_3.05.jar,file:/usr/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar],parent=null]] 
Loaded from file:/mnt/nand/lu/lib/derby.jar
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
user.dir=/mnt/nand/lu
os.name=Linux
os.arch=sh3
os.version=2.6.25.9-svn298-dirty2
derby.system.home=null
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
Wed Oct 02 05:53:23 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 33536), (SESSIONID = 3), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Cleanup action starting
Wed Oct 02 05:53:23 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 33536), (SESSIONID = 3), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Failed Statement is: SELECT device.serial_number, tariff,reference_power_active, overload_power_limit_active, breaker_state,logical_device_type.name FROM device, logical_device_type WHERE device.id_logical_device_type = logical_device_type.id AND serial_number='041068350153'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.derby.exe.ac601a400fx0141x75cax8140x00000006841480.createResultSet(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.CursorActivation.decorateResultSet(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BaseActivation.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericActivationHolder.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.g.a.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.g.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.g.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.statemachine.b.e.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.statemachine.b.i.c(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.statemachine.SmartHub.A(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.statemachine.SmartHub.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.statemachine.SmartHub.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.CVM.runMain(Unknown Source)
Cleanup action completed
Wed Oct 02 06:15:26 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 34359), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Cleanup action starting
Wed Oct 02 06:15:26 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 34359), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Failed Statement is: SELECT device.serial_number, tariff,reference_power_active, overload_power_limit_active, breaker_state,logical_device_type.name FROM device, logical_device_type WHERE device.id_logical_device_type = logical_device_type.id AND serial_number='041067350131'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.derby.exe.ac601a400fx0141x75cax8140x00000006841485.createResultSet(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.CursorActivation.decorateResultSet(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BaseActivation.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericActivationHolder.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.g.a.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.g.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.g.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.statemachine.b.e.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.statemachine.b.i.c(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.statemachine.SmartHub.A(Compiled Method)(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.statemachine.SmartHub.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.s.statemachine.SmartHub.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.CVM.runMain(Unknown Source)
Cleanup action completed
```

Here is the structure of the table:

```
private final static String               MCS_TABLE      = "metering_campaign_strategy";
private final static String[]             MCS_COLS       = { "serial_number",
            "measure_kind", "frequencyUnit", "frequency", "begin_date", "end_date", "last_retrieve_date" };
private final static String[]             MCS_COLS_TYPES = { "varchar(40) NOT NULL",
            "varchar(15) NOT NULL", "varchar(10) NOT NULL", "integer", "timestamp NOT NULL", "timestamp", "timestamp" }
```

;

As you can see, the table where the problem occurs is created programmatically.

I added the DumpClassFile option, will update this post as soon as I get a result

As requested, here's the the schema of the database;

```
Wed Oct 02 18:53:14 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 165), (SESSIONID = 0), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
Wed Oct 02 18:53:14 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 165), (SESSIONID = 0), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Rolling back
Wed Oct 02 18:53:14 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 166), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
Wed Oct 02 18:53:15 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 167), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Begin compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE device (serial_number varchar(40), id_logical_device_type integer, tariff varchar(16), reference_power_active integer, overload_power_limit_active integer, breaker_state integer) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:21 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 167), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), End compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE device (serial_number varchar(40), id_logical_device_type integer, tariff varchar(16), reference_power_active integer, overload_power_limit_active integer, breaker_state integer) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:22 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 167), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Executing prepared statement: CREATE TABLE device (serial_number varchar(40), id_logical_device_type integer, tariff varchar(16), reference_power_active integer, overload_power_limit_active integer, breaker_state integer) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:23 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 167), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
Wed Oct 02 18:53:24 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 171), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Begin compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE measure (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date timestamp NOT NULL, value decimal(12,2), type integer, sent boolean) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:24 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 171), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), End compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE measure (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date timestamp NOT NULL, value decimal(12,2), type integer, sent boolean) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:24 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 171), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Executing prepared statement: CREATE TABLE measure (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date timestamp NOT NULL, value decimal(12,2), type integer, sent boolean) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:26 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 171), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
Wed Oct 02 18:53:27 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 184), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Begin compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE message (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date integer, message varchar(100)) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:27 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 184), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), End compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE message (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date integer, message varchar(100)) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:27 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 184), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Executing prepared statement: CREATE TABLE message (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date integer, message varchar(100)) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:27 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 184), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
Wed Oct 02 18:53:28 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 187), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Begin compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE logical_device_type (id integer, name varchar(100)) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:28 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 187), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), End compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE logical_device_type (id integer, name varchar(100)) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:28 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 187), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Executing prepared statement: CREATE TABLE logical_device_type (id integer, name varchar(100)) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:28 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 187), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
Wed Oct 02 18:53:29 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 193), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Begin compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE load_curve (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date timestamp NOT NULL, value integer, error integer, sent boolean) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:29 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 193), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), End compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE load_curve (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date timestamp NOT NULL, value integer, error integer, sent boolean) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:29 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 193), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Executing prepared statement: CREATE TABLE load_curve (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date timestamp NOT NULL, value integer, error integer, sent boolean) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:29 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 193), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
Wed Oct 02 18:53:29 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 196), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Begin compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE load_curve_last_collect (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date timestamp NOT NULL) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:30 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 196), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), End compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE load_curve_last_collect (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date timestamp NOT NULL) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:30 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 196), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Executing prepared statement: CREATE TABLE load_curve_last_collect (id_device varchar(40) NOT NULL, date timestamp NOT NULL) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:30 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 196), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
Wed Oct 02 18:53:30 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 199), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Begin compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE tariff (type integer, name varchar(100)) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:30 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 199), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), End compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE tariff (type integer, name varchar(100)) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:30 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 199), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Executing prepared statement: CREATE TABLE tariff (type integer, name varchar(100)) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:31 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 199), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
Wed Oct 02 18:53:31 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 202), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Begin compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE state_configuration (state_name varchar(50), last_execution timestamp) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:31 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 202), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), End compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE state_configuration (state_name varchar(50), last_execution timestamp) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:31 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 202), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Executing prepared statement: CREATE TABLE state_configuration (state_name varchar(50), last_execution timestamp) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:31 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 202), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
Wed Oct 02 18:53:32 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 205), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Begin compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE metering_campaign_strategy (serial_number varchar(40) NOT NULL, measure_kind varchar(15) NOT NULL, frequencyUnit varchar(10) NOT NULL, frequency integer, begin_date timestamp NOT NULL, end_date timestamp, last_retrieve_date timestamp) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:32 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 205), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), End compiling prepared statement: CREATE TABLE metering_campaign_strategy (serial_number varchar(40) NOT NULL, measure_kind varchar(15) NOT NULL, frequencyUnit varchar(10) NOT NULL, frequency integer, begin_date timestamp NOT NULL, end_date timestamp, last_retrieve_date timestamp) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:32 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 205), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Executing prepared statement: CREATE TABLE metering_campaign_strategy (serial_number varchar(40) NOT NULL, measure_kind varchar(15) NOT NULL, frequencyUnit varchar(10) NOT NULL, frequency integer, begin_date timestamp NOT NULL, end_date timestamp, last_retrieve_date timestamp) :End prepared statement
Wed Oct 02 18:53:33 CEST 2013 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 205), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = smarthubdb), (DRDAID = null), Committing
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a connection pool? Could you be getting a stale connection out of it?

Comment: No, we are not using a connection pool. A Connection object holds the connection to the database, and is used to get a statement object that executes the queyr

Comment: Is this the entire trace? There's 15 minutes between the start of the trace and the first database activity. What happens if you access the database very soon after the application starts?

Comment: !yes this the entire trace. I think that by default Derby does not log everything, am gonna change that and see what comes out of it!

Comment: And what happens if you access the database soon after starting the app. Where I'm heading is that it _may_ be that the connection or statement has become stale in the 15 mins of inactivity since the app was initialized.

Comment: *"An null pointer exception occurs for no apparent reason."* nothing in programming happens for *"no apparent reason"*, you may not recognize the reason but that doesn't mean it is randomly happening.

Comment: In most cases, all goes well (even if no access to the DB is done right away). The problem that you mentioned may be the problem, not really sure how to check this though, may be disconnect after each query and reconnect before (I don't really like this option since the application is running on a limited resources equipment and the connection/disconnection to/from the DB takes up to 90 seconds). What I really find bizarre is that everything goes back to normal afterwards (some data is lost though due to the failed queries)

Comment: A I've said earlier, Derby wasn't logging everythin (only the startup and the exceptions) so it may look like that nothing happens. Just added the option that allows Derby to log everything and will be updating this post when I have more useful data

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenge to debug, as the crash is occurring inside generated code while executing your query.

In the case of your query, the generated code is probably evaluating the restriction predicates (WHERE serial_number = '041169700007' AND measure_kind='INDEX')

For a start, here's a bit of information about how to learn more about what's inside that generated code: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DumpClassFile

The fact that the problem seems to occur intermittently makes it still harder, as without a reproducible case you will have trouble tracking down and resolving the bug.

Is your application single threaded? Or are there multiple threads running?

Have you checked for out-of-resouce issues? Running out of JVM memory, running out of disk space, etc.?

One thing that might be worth considering is whether the Derby statement cache is coming in to play. Does disabling the cache affect the problem? http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/StatementCache

You mention that the database schema (tables, indexes, etc) is created dynamically. Can you update your question to include the exact schema information? One way to get this is to run 'dblook' against your database after running your application. Or run your application with '-Dderby.language.logStatementText=true', and all the SQL statements that are executed should be echoed to the log.

If you don't get very far on your own, you might try contacting the Derby community on the Apache mailing lists, as they will have more suggestions for you to try.

Comment: The application is single threaded. For sure there is enough disk space, as far as the memory is concerned, I didn't get any message of the sort (in some cases, we will have the exception for like 30 minutes, then everything will go back to normal for an hour or two). I will try running the cvm with a bit more heap/stack. I will update my post to include more information

Comment: Just edited my question to add the information you requested. I will look into the statement cache and post if I find anything interesting

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply you have some data that is `NULL` for some reason that you have not identified some of the time and `NOT NULL` other times.

If this data is coming from the database, making all the columns `NOT NULLABLE` will expose where `NULL` data is being inserted.

If the data is coming from your model code, then you can use the JSR 305 library from [Google](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.findbugs%7Cfindbugs%7C2.0.1%7Cjar) to annotate everything with `@Nonnull` in all your method signatures and you will find where `NULL` references are being passed.

Both of these things will increase the maintainability and quality of your code in the long run either way.